# Adding a border to an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to add a border to an alert dialog. I am hoping to make it look like this:

[image]

The best solution I have found thus far is to use a nine patch drawable as the background for the dialog.

The problem with this is that I have not found a way to make a nine patch background that actually gives the dialog a consistent white line around it. This has been my best attempt thus far (sorry it is a little hard to see...) :

[image]

The problem is that this produces a dialog like this:

[image]

The problems here are twofold; the lines at the sides are way too thick, and the lines at the top are kind of faded by the shadow.

My only ideas are to either find a working nine patch that gives a consistently thick border, or to find a way to get the 'main layout' of the alert dialog, so I can add a padding to that directly.

What is the best way to go about setting up a border on an Alert Dialog like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer by questioner was very close to what I wanted, but it still left a big black line around the dialog that I was not interested in.

I deleted one of the layers from the layer list, and customised the padding on the white border. I also did **not** set the background to transparent as suggested would be a good idea in the comments.

The shape the is inside the item is to give the background the same curved edges on a dialog (if you look really closely on 3.0+, you can see a few pixels of round corners).

In a `dialog_border.xml` file in the `drawable` folder, I had this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="6dp"
        android:left="13dp"
        android:right="13dp"
        android:bottom="6dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/offWhite" />

            <corners
                android:radius="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And in my style I had this:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_border</item>
</style>
```

Although it could probably be set programatically rather than in the style if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In your dialog's xml set following background for top level view:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:drawable="@color/black"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

You can customise border width on each side.

Comment: Thanks; this approach seems promising... But how do I make the border only 1-2dp wide? There is still a massive black chunk of space between the dialog and the white border.

Comment: @jcw Did you try setting this drawable as your background? You can freely customise border's width. If there are any artifacts from dialog's style try this: `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);` in your on constructor or `onCreateDialog`.

Comment: Yes, I set this as my dialog's background, but it has the same problem as the image in my question (except part of the border is black instead). There is a 15-20dp wide black border that I am trying to get rid of, followed by the thin white line I am after. Setting the background to transparent is not what I am trying to do; I am trying to get a normal dialog, with a white border.... Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: I made a few adjustments to the layer list you provided and got it to work in the end (see my answer). Thanks again for all the help

Comment: @jcw Could you try removing/commenting out `dialogStyle` or `dialogTheme` from your applications' theme and see if white extra border is gone? I noticed that with this property gone and setting theme programatically in dialogs' 'onCreateDialog()` solves issue with unwanted white border. Let me know.